# Jmeter cookies clearing for only one transaction

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario that user will only login once and perform all the transcations for one hour and at last user will logout i have tried with thread group with loopcontroller ,once only and runtime controller but not able to achieve it

And also on part of load test whenever user has logged in and performing other transcations if he gets any eroor and he need to login again with clearing cookies but not for entire transcations because after login remaining transcations require those cookies please help how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following setup:

1. Put login logic under [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/)
2. Pass authentication context (cookies or whatever) to main Thread Group using [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)
3. Put logout logic under [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

Your requirement in case of "if he gets any eroor" doesn't make a lot of sense to me in its current form as I cannot get the desired behaviour.